# Java applet stutters on first time drawing a BufferedImage (Java2D)

Tags: java, applet, bufferedimage, java-2d

I am writing a game as a java applet using the Java2D libraries along with the BufferedImage class. The game stutters (2-3 seconds) the very first time an image is drawn. The BufferImage files are all loaded before the game begins, using this method:

```
bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);       
    try {
           URL url = new URL(a.getCodeBase(), "images//smoke5frames.png");
           bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(url);           
    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }        
    mSmoke = bufferedImage;
```

To draw the image, I am using this method:

```
public void draw(Graphics2D g) {    
g.drawImage(mTextures[iCurrentFrame], mAffineTransform, null); }
```

The images in question are SheetedSprites, typically cut from a sprite sheet using:

```
for each frame in animation...

myBufferedImage.getSubimage(i * iFrameWidth, 0, iFrameWidth, iHeight);
```

Which is done during game play when the entity is created. Removing this line did not solve the problem, so I am assuming (perhaps poorly) getSubimage() isn't expensive enough to cause the issue.

I could loop though each and every frame of animation and draw them all for a quick-fix, but I'd like to understand more about the problem and why it happens.

The kicker is that once the SheetedSprite has been drawn once, you can refresh the page and the problem doesn't occur again. The game runs perfectly smoothly after everything has been drawn before. This is the case in both IE and Chrome (I haven't tried it on any other browsers). As a side note, the problem never occurs in Eclipse's Applet Viewer.

My best guess is that the images are somehow cached by the browser, though really I'm stumped. I haven't tried loading/drawing images with a different set of graphical libraries either (Slick2D, LWJGL, etc). Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Where is `draw(G2D)` called from & how is the graphics object obtained?  Actually no, scratch that exact question, provide the answer as an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Here is a zip for a project that showcases the method used to draw images: http://dan.nemmons.net/stack/UnprofStackQuestion.zip

In the Applet subclass, I create an Image object with the dimensions of the screen. I get the Graphics member of this Image via image.getGraphics(). Each draw call, I clear the graphics, and pass them to the game which casts the Graphics object to Graphics2D. From here the game calls sprite.draw(graphics2d) on all sprites. Lastly, at the end of the Applet's draw method, I draw the Image to the screen.

Comment: Can you make the code short enough that it is an SSCCE you can post as an edit?  That is what I will look at.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem about 2 years ago, and I found a fix for it on the great Java-gaming.org. The problem for me, was that Java has a problem with certain kinds of png-files. Some would cause lag when utilized for the first time, and some wouldn't. This "fixer-upper-method" takes a BufferedImage, and returns a BufferedImage, but in between, it does some magic, that makes the image easier for Java to decode (don't ask me how).
Enjoy!

```
private BufferedImage toCompatibleImage(BufferedImage image)
{
    if(image==null)System.out.println("Image is null");
    // obtain the current system graphical settings
    GraphicsConfiguration gfx_config = GraphicsEnvironment.
            getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().
            getDefaultConfiguration();

    /*
     * if image is already compatible and optimized for current system 
     * settings, simply return it
     */
    if (image.getColorModel().equals(gfx_config.getColorModel()))
            return image;

    // image is not optimized, so create a new image that is
    BufferedImage new_image = gfx_config.createCompatibleImage(
                    image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), image.getTransparency());

    // get the graphics context of the new image to draw the old image on
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) new_image.getGraphics();

    // actually draw the image and dispose of context no longer needed
    g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g2d.dispose();

    // return the new optimized image
    return new_image; 
}
```